# Cant access state inside reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have createslice and reducer like this. I want to print my state inside reducer cause my dispatch is not working correctly but when i am trying to printing the state.event i am getting this.

```
[Proxy]
0: Proxy {}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

export const eventSlice = createSlice({
      name: 'event',
      initialState: {
        event: [],
        favouriteEvents: [],
        isFetching: false,
        isSuccess: false,
        isError: false,
        errorMessage: '',
      },
    
      reducers: {
        alterFavourite: (state, action) => {
       // item = state.event.filter((item) => {
       //   item.pk == parseInt(pk)
       // item.is_liked = !is_liked;
       // })
    
        console.log(state.event)
      },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [current](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/current) function:

> Immer exposes a named export `current` that creates a copy of the current state of the draft. This can be very useful for debugging purposes (as those objects won't be Proxy objects and not be logged as such). Also, references to `current` can be safely leaked from a produce function. Put differently, `current` provides a snapshot of the current state of a draft.

RTK uses immer underly and re-exports these functions. The state in the reducer is a `draft` object, it is some kind of wrapper or proxy of the JavaScript plain object.

You can do this:

```js
import { configureStore, createSlice, current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const eventSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'event',
  initialState: {
    event: [],
    favouriteEvents: [],
    isFetching: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isError: false,
    errorMessage: '',
  },

  reducers: {
    alterFavourite: (state, action) => {
      // console.log(state.event);
      console.log('current state.event: ', current(state.event));
    },
  },
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    event: eventSlice.reducer,
  },
});
store.dispatch(eventSlice.actions.alterFavourite(null));
```

Output:

```sh
current state.event:  []
```

package version: `"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1"`

Comment: @AbuSayem See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#immutable-updates-with-immer

Comment: Hi. Thanks now i can access state. but I want to filter and change an event of state.event's  is_liked property. How can i do that. for example in tutorial they are accessing state like that  ```const todo = state.find(todo => todo.id === action.payload) ```but i am not able to daccess ```state``` like that

Comment: @AbuSayem Read the tutorials and try if the issue is still there. Ask a new question.