# How to properly check action.payload for existence in the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm trying create function that to place action.payload into store if it not exist there, otherwise delete it.

```
state.selected = []; //initial
action.payload = {...}
```

**Slice.ts:**

```
  userSelect(state, action: PayloadAction<IUser>) {
            if (state.selected.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < state.selected.length + 1; i++) {
                    if (state.selected[i].id === action.payload.id) {   //state.selected[i] -> Proxy; state.selected[i].id = undefined
                        state.selected.filter(e => e !== action.payload)
                    } else {
                        state.selected = state.selected || []
                        state.selected.push(action.payload)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                state.selected = state.selected || []
                state.selected.push(action.payload)
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to check array state.selected for existence action.payload by its id, but i cant get id from within state.selected, because it's Proxy type, and my logs for checking single e.g. state.selected[0] returns as `Proxy {i: 0, A: {…}, P: false, I: false, D: {…}, …}`

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69657322/6463558 answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For logging, you can `import { current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'` and `console.log(current(state))`.
Also, please note that `.filter` does not change your array, but returns a new one, so you would have to do `state.selected = state.selected.filter(e => e !== action.payload)`

Generally:

```js
const foundIdx = state.selected.findIndex(selected => selected.id === action.payload.id)
if (foundIdx >= 0) {
  state.selected.splice(foundIdx, 1)
} else {
  state.selected.push(action.payload)
}
```

should do all you need

Comment: Huge thanks, that was the solution!